# what is the difference between web demo and multichain explorer?

Tags: blockchain

I installed multichain at my server and then i run the multichain -daemon.
I have to setup a private blockchain with cluster of nodes. Can you please help with what i need to check in web demo and multichain explorer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Demo is for performing blockchain actions, such as changing permissions, sending assets, publishing items, syncing of multiple nodes together at the same time when a new block is added etc...

The Explorer is for browsing what has happened on the blockchain but it cannot initiate actions.

No, not all the Explorer functionality is in the Web Demo. I would recommend trying both to see exactly what they can and cannot do for you.

Comment: thanks man ! i will give it a try and if i have any problem i will ask here. Thank you for your support. I see very less questions related to multichain have been answered here.